# How can I show duplicate rows using MySQL "LIKE"?

Tags: mysql, sql-like

I have table with following structure and test records:

```
+--------+--------+---------+
| vid    | number | name    |
+--------+--------+---------+
| 2      | 012345 | name1   | r1
| 6      | 0012345| 1name   | r2
| 5      | 012345 | namee   | r3
| 6      | 9111522| name6   | r4
| 3      | 999999 | name65  | r5
| 2      | 0999999| name64  | r6
+--------+--------+---------+
```

The rows r1, r2 and r3 are duplicated, because 12345 is inside in the field number and r5 and r6 are duplicated. 
I want to show duplicate rows from this table.

What query I must to create to get this result?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're storing your "number" column as a string (VARCHAR). If that is the case I'd highly recommend you switch it to an INT column type. If that's not possible then I'd make sure your app normalises the data on the way in so the string-formatted numbers are always in the same format. It will make life much easier.

Anyway in terms of the data that's there, assuming that a duplicate means "the numeric representations of the data are the same" then this would work

```
SELECT
  t1.vid, t1.number, t1.name
FROM table t1
  INNER JOIN table t2
  ON CAST(t1.number AS SIGNED)=CAST(t2.number AS SIGNED) AND t1.vid!=t2.vid
GROUP BY t1.vid
```

Comment: This is a more complete and better answer than mine.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following query which doesn't limit you to a particular pattern. Add the regexp in Michaels answer to the WHERE clause in order to group by pattern.

```
SELECT
    t1.id, t1.number, t1.name
FROM table t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table t2
ON t1.number LIKE CONCAT('%', t2.number, '%')
GROUP BY t1.id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

**UPDATE**
By adding the CAST signed function to the above query, we can get all leading 0 entries removed.

```
SELECT
    t1.id, t1.number, t1.name
FROM table t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table t2
ON t1.number LIKE CONCAT('%', CAST(t2.number AS SIGNED), '%')
GROUP BY t1.id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Here is a link to the MYSQL fiddle demonstrating the query on sample data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4deee/2